# SSH Error from Nexus 5K to Linux

Tags: ssh, cisco-nexus

I built a CLI shortcut to ssh the config over to an Ubuntu box (with an SMB share mounted to the user home directory).

```
cli alias name archive copy startup-config scp://sw-backup@1.1.1.3//home/sw-backup/Cisco/Switch/Nexus/NexusB vrf default
```

This is so I can easily push my config out to a Windows file server via the "SSH gateway" box.  I tried some freebie and Trial SSH Server software on Windows and had too many reliability issues.  That was resolved with the Linux box in the middle.  It's been stable for quite some time.

I copy files over to this server from all of our routers, switches and Call Manager backups.

I recently updated Nexus to version 7.1(4)N1(1).  Now when I attempt to copy I receive an error:

```
nnn-nexus-b# archive
No matching ciphers found. Client (10.130.9.35) supported ciphers :
aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.
se .Server supported ciphers : chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128
-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openss
h.com

lost connection

nnn-nexus-b#
```

I found the following that looks promising:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/nexus-9000-series-switches/200663-Unable-to-SSH-into-Nexus-9K-fatal.html

The above link references the SSH Server on the Nexus.  I'm reaching out to an Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS machine.  I can't enable the bash shell feature on the 5548UP.  I'm guessing I can disable the weak ciphers on Ubuntu.

Here lies the problem.  Call Manager backups, IOS and IOS-XE devices are still using the weak cipher if I understand what's going on correctly.  If I change the Ubuntu box, I'll break all of these.

What are some thoughts on how to work around this?

Thanks,
B-Dog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, find the line `Ciphers` and add one of the ciphers your Nexus supports (say, `aes256-cbc`) to it, keeping the ciphers you already have enabled for your other devices.  If the line is not there, add it with the list the server is advertising in your error message and add that cipher to the end eg:

```
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-cbc
```

`man sshd_config` should list the ciphers your version of openssh supports in the Ciphers section.

Comment: Perfect - I appreciate your help.  sshd_config didn't have the Ciphers line.  I'm guessing the latest Ubuntu update hardened this.  The man page shows that aes256-cbc is no longer a default.